# How to Make Form Inputs Vertical Rather Than Horizontal Using CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms

I know this is a very basic question; I'm new to coding and doing my first course from FreeCodeCamp.

I have to put together a survey form and the inputs default to displaying horizontally. I've looked for hours and can't figure out how to make them display vertically instead. Here is the codepen of the form: https://codepen.io/callowaycodes/pen/wvKBPej

Some of the examples I've seen online have been quite complex for such a simple solution. Is there no way to just apply one or two lines of CSS to the form ID to achieve this effect, in this section:

```
#survey-form {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: in your codepen demo, just add this css -> `label {display:block}`.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do without entering into flexbox properties it's to wrap each `input` and `label` elements into a `div` element (block element) since inputs and label are by default inline elements and that's why they are stacked one side each other. Inline elements takes it's content width, and block elements takes 100% width.

Simple Example:

```
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Link with resolution:
https://codepen.io/fenwil/pen/oNjgQKw

Comment: Very cool, thank you! FreeCodeCamp is interesting but I think the issue is they don't teach the "why" for things like this, they just have you play around with different effects, so when you try to make your own sample page you have no theoretical understanding of things like this. Do you have any recommendations for better free courses for amateurs?

Comment: I recommend freeCodeCamp and keep sticking to it because it's focused is to dive directly into practice. When you need more detailed information about HTML & CSS refer to https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/ and for JavaScript refer to https://javascript.info/ .Also Mozilla Developer Network should be your daily bible for short and updated documentation related to any web concept https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.